# “Cannot run program” when using Runtime.exec with spaces in command

Tags: java, powershell, processbuilder

> cmd=powershell.exe;$passwd=convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force -String abc;$cred=new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "xyz",$passwd;$session=new-PSSession -Computer mobilesaucelabs.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com -Credential $cred -UseSSL;Invoke-Command -Session $session -FilePath C:\FetchMfilesVersion.ps1

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

It throws error because of spaces.

Could someone please let me know how to run the above command using java.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string[] cmd = {"powershell.exe;$passwd=convertto-securestring", "-AsPlainText", "-Force", "-String", "abc;$cred=new-object", "-typename", "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential", "-argumentlist 'xyz'","$passwd;$session=new-PSSession", "-Computer", "mobilesaucelabs.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com", "-Credential", "$cred", "-UseSSL;Invoke-Command", "-Session", "$session", "AddCodeWithSpacesSoOn"};

Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```